# access files for language packs in Google Translate android app

Tags: android, google-translate

Is it possible for Google Translate and two languages (let's say english and spanish) to be installed on a device with **no** internet access?

It's easy enough to get the .apk and sideload Google Translate - but is there any way to get a copy of the offline language packs for use in the app once it's installed? The only 'official' way is through downloading, but I'd like to be able to install the app from an .apk, then copy some language files into some system folders, and have the app recognize that those languages are available when it starts up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes it is possible to download the offline language packs directly from google servers and
then copy them to your phone's data folder of translate app.

check out following link...you can find the links and the procedure to download the zip files
for offline language packs and install them.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2234606&page=2